# How I can access calendar from Office add-in app?

Tags: calendar, office365, outlook-addin

I'm creating a Mail Add-in for Office 365. I want to get access to calendar. Using [Outlook Add-in API](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/index.html) I get only selected item:

```
   var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
// Continue with processing the subject of the current item, 
// which can be a message or appointment.
```

I found [Calendar REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations), but to get a valid token I need obtain the appropriate authorization. But I'm already authorized in my add-in. I don't want to redirect user to authorize again when he has added my add-in and already granted the access to it. Is it possible to get access to calendar from my add-in without additional authorization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time there is no single sign-on support between an Office ad-in and Graph.  You can follow the approach outlined in this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2015/08/10/connecting-to-office-365-from-an-office-add-in.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Eric Legault has post a good approach and I have used it. However, I have found a possibility to access to calendar from mailbox without any **OAuth** authorizations like with **Graph API**.

You can use [makeEwsRequestAsync](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.html#makeEwsRequestAsync) method to make an asynchronous request (SOAP messages) to an Exchange Web Services (EWS) service on the Exchange server that hosts the user’s mailbox. 
Your add-in must have the **ReadWriteMailbox** permission and the server administrator must set **OAuthAuthentication** to true on the Client Access Server EWS directory to enable this method to make EWS requests. 
You can find [EWS reference for Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb204119(v=exchg.150).aspx) to learn how to build proper SOAP for your request.